# Xcode: The session is inactive. Please check your setup and try again. 0xE800001E

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, organizer

This happens after I hit **Build and Go** to run my app on my device.

**Build -> Clean** fixes it, but it's very annoying to have to clean and rebuild the entire project every time I want to run it.

*P.S. Is there any way to transfer my app to my iPhone using Xcode, but not run it?*

Comment: I am getting this too all of a sudden and sometimes doing a clean all doesn't even fix it. Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A restart of the device and Xcode seems to have fixed it for me.
At least for now...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill all your background app if youre running on iOS 4.0 or above.